# Fourier series of $sgn(\cos(x))$

Tags: fourier-series

Knowing formulas for Fourier series when I'm given interval $(0,2l)$ & $(-l,l)$ I can't seem to find Fourier series of $sgn(\cos(x))$. I know that  $a_n = \frac{2}{l} \int_0^{l}f(x)\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{l})dx$, $b_n$ same but with $\sin$. If I'm given interval $(0,2l)$ then $a_n = \frac{1}{l} \int_{\lambda}^{\lambda + 2l}f(x)\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{l})dx$, $b_n$ same where we usually put $\lambda = 0$.

My question is if I have that my function $sgn(cos(x))$ is:

$\begin{cases}
 1&\text{if}\, x \in [\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]\\
 -1&\text{if}\, x \in [\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]\\
\end{cases}
$

What interval I should use for my Fourier series and this is the part where my understanding of this fails. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't edit sgn to sin. I mean sgn as a sign function not as sine.

Comment: To integrate a picewise function, you can split the domain of integration into multiple intervals (at the points where the function changes pieces) and use the appropriate piece in each of the resulting integrals.

Comment: Take $T=2\pi$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2143547)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your function is $2\pi$ periodic you only need any intervall of the length $2\pi$. As the following shows:
Let $a\in\mathbb R$ then we can write $a=2\pi k+r$ with $r\in[0,2\pi)$ and $k\in \mathbb Z$.

$$\pi a_n=\int_a^{a+2\pi}f(x)\text{cos}(nx)dx=\int_{2\pi k+r}^{2\pi(k+1)+r}f(x)\text{cos}(nx)dx=\int_r^{2\pi  +r}f(x+2\pi k)\text{cos}(nx+2\pi nk)dx$$
Where the last step is just an easy substitution. Now we use that $f$ is $2\pi$ periodic, so we get:
$$\pi a_n=\int_r^{2\pi +r}f(x)\text{cos}(nx) dx=\int_r^{2\pi}f(x)\text{cos}(nx)dx+\int_{2\pi}^{2\pi+r}f(x)\text{cos}(nx)dx$$
Now we use again the periodicity on the right hand term:
$$\int_{2\pi}^{2\pi+r}f(x)\text{cos}(nx)dx=\int_{0}^{r}f(x+2\pi)\text{cos}(nx+2\pi n)dx=\int_{0}^{r}f(x)\text{cos}(nx)dx$$
Combined it follows:
$$\pi a_n=\int_a^{a+2\pi}f(x)\text{cos}(nx)dx=\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\text{cos}(nx)dx$$

As you can see, the acutal interval ist not that important, you only need an interval of leingh $2\pi$.